# finding names of un-named list elements

Tags: r

I have a naming problem: lists with un-named elements.  I wish to get the names of the elements in the list, without going back upstream to where the list was created. An example is `modelList` below:

```
## naming problem
lmNms <- c( "mod1", "mod2", "mod3", "mod4", "mod5", "mod6")
lapply(lmNms, 
       function(N) assign(N, lm(runif(10) ~ rnorm(10)), env = .GlobalEnv))
modelList <- list(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5, mod6)
```

I have written the below function which takes the list and the `environment` as arguments (as well as an argument to return names only), looks for a matching object in the target environment, and then attaches that name to the element and returns the list.

```
nameListObjects <- function(LIST, ENV = NULL, NAMES.ONLY = FALSE) {
    if(is.null(ENV)) ENV <- .GlobalEnv
    for(i in seq_along(LIST)){
        # check the class of all objects in the target environment
        classMatches <- sapply(ls(ENV), 
                               function(N) class(get(N)) == class(LIST[[i]]))
        # see which objects of matching class are all.equal to the subject
        TF <- sapply(names(classMatches[classMatches]), 
                 function(N) is.logical(all.equal(LIST[[i]], get(N))))
        names(LIST)[i] <- names(classMatches[classMatches])[TF]
    }
    if(NAMES.ONLY) names(LIST) else LIST
}

R>nameListObjects(modelList, NAMES.ONLY=TRUE)
[1] "mod1" "mod2" "mod3" "mod4" "mod5" "mod6"
```

This took me to the edge of my R ability.

I'm interested in better ways to do this (i presume there are multiple better ways), problems with this approach, and any other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used `identical` to compare objects. However, I would recommend representing all objects by their MD5 digests, so you can then use `match` to find the matches:

```
nameListObjects <- function(LIST, ENV = NULL, NAMES.ONLY = FALSE) {

  if(is.null(ENV)) ENV <- .GlobalEnv
  require(digest)
  list.md5   <- sapply(LIST, digest)
  env.names  <- ls(envir = ENV)
  env.md5    <- sapply(env.names, function(x)digest(get(x, envir = ENV)))
  list.names <- env.names[match(list.md5, env.md5)]

  if(NAMES.ONLY) list.names else setNames(LIST, list.names)
}

nameListObjects(modelList, NAMES.ONLY=TRUE)
[1] "mod1" "mod2" "mod3" "mod4" "mod5" "mod6"
```

Comment: +1, thanks. I don't know what an MD5 digest is -- can you please explain a little?

Comment: I'd recommend you google it for a better explanation, but the idea is that a fast algorithm reads and converts an object's contents into a character string e.g. `digest(mod1)` is `f7c95caf2caafd8603977ac967f0ebe2`. As you can guess from the length and complexity of the string, the probability of two distinct objects sharing the same digest is very, very small. It's like a fingerprint in a sense.